# Dynamic title with submit form (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, dynamic, title, form-submit, getparameter

I'm trying to make an job board with wordpress and have the following issue:

On a common page you will see all the avaiable jobs. If you click on a job you will go to a job page. This is just working fine.

The next step shoud be a submit form with the job title. It should be like this:

JOBS Page --> JOB XXX --> SUBMIT form with the job title/id.

- How can i get the jobs title on the form page?
- How can i send the dynamic title/id etc of that page to my mailbox with contact form 7 (dynamic text extension).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current page title by using `post_title` and can put it in a hidden field.
**Something like below**

```
<input type="hidden" id="job_title" name="job_title" value="<?php echo $post->post_title; ?>"/>
```

On the submitted page:

```
$jobtitle = $_REQUEST['job_title']; // and you can mail this by using mail() function
```